# How to go back n levels of directories from the command line?

Tags: shell, directory, cd-command

For example, I do the following `cd`s in succession-

```
cd /tmp
cd /home/admin
cd /root/
cd /some_other/directory
```

Now I am in `/some_other/directory`. Now, is there anyway to go back to `/tmp`, the directory from where I started, from the command line? Just like we navigate directories using the back button in the GUI?

`cd -` just takes me one level back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is shell specific. In a pure POSIX shell, you can't without typing cd /tmp again. In csh, tcsh, bash or zsh, you can use `pushd` instead of `cd` to change directories and then `popd +1` to cd to the first directory you pushed onto the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Read [this article](http://linuxgazette.net/109/marinov.html) from LinuxGazette on adding a history to `cd` with a few simple scripts. It's quite usable.

If you want to be fancy, then there is a program called `autojump` (homepage [here](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki)) which keeps history of the directories visited, provides shortcuts and generally supports "intelligent" `cd`.

> autojump is a faster way to navigate your filesystem. It works by maintaining a database of the directories you use the most from the command line. The jumpstat command shows you the current contents of the database. You need to work a little bit before the database becomes usable. Once your database is reasonably complete, you can “jump” to a commonly "cd"ed directory by typing: `j dirspec`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same problem and came across below workaround/shortcut for changing n directories back.

Just add the following to the bash_profile if you are using a bash shell.  For other shell's use it according to their syntax.

```
    alias ..="cd .."
    alias ..2="cd ../.."
    alias ..3="cd ../../.."
    alias ..4="cd ../../../.."
    alias ..5="cd ../../../../.."

    # cd /tmp/very/long/directory/structure/that/is/too/deep
    #..4
    [Note: use ..4 to go up 4 directory level]
    # pwd
    /tmp/very/long/directory/structure/
```

You can also use just dots instead of dots followed by a number. Detailed description is available in the below link.

Source : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/6-awesome-linux-cd-command-hacks-productivity-tip3-for-geeks/

Comment: That's not what they asked though... Also, you can make it easier with a subroutine: `back () { for i in \`seq 0 $1\`; do cd ../; done }` and then call `back 3` for example. But the question asker wanted to know how to go several cd history steps back.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.. I was thinking this is one way of jumping from current directory to where he started if he remember how many directories he passed by. Your subroutine call is nice, its much easier to define and use.

Comment: you seems misunderstood the question. question is not about go directories back from the current path each time, it's about to call the Nth cd command back which was executed